# WebGL and GLM issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I'm trying to create a 3D webgl render but I don't know why it's not working. I'm using webgl, and glm.

I've a similar code working on c++ but I'm trying to make the same on webGL.

Can anyone guide me on what the issue could be? I'm not having any error but it is not rendering inside the canvas.

This is my .js file and my html only contains the canvas.

```js
var gl; // 
var canvas;
var gfx;
function start() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
  gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');


    gfx = make_gfx();



      gl.clearColor(0.9,0.9,0.8,1);
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


     // gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 6);
     render();
      //draw_text(0,0,0,"asd",0,0,0,0,0,0);
    //gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    draw_line(10,10,10,100,100,100,0,0,255);
}


function make_gfx() {
    var gfx = new GraphicState();
        gfx.ctx = gl;
        gfx.window = canvas;
        gfx.shader = gl.createProgram();

  //  var vtx_shader = make_shader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, "#version 330 es layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;layout (location = 1) in vec2 tex_coord;out float _alpha;uniform mat4 model;uniform mat4 view;uniform mat4 projection;uniform int line;uniform float player_y;uniform float obj_y;void main(){if (line > 0) {gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(pos, 1.0f);_alpha = line / 255.0f;} else {gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0f);_alpha = abs(player_y - obj_y) >= 3.0f ? 0.25f : 1.0f;}}");
   // var pixel_shader = make_shader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, "#version 330 es out vec4 FragColor; in float _alpha; uniform vec3 color; void main(){FragColor = vec4(color, _alpha);}");
    var vtx_shader = make_shader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, " #version 300 es \n" +
        "\n" +
        "            " +
        "in vec3 pos;\n" +
        "in vec2 tex_coord;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "            out float _alpha;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "            uniform mat4 model;\n" +
        "            uniform mat4 view;\n" +
        "            uniform mat4 projection;\n" +
        "            uniform int line;\n" +
        "            uniform float player_y;\n" +
        "            uniform float obj_y;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "            void main()\n" +
        "            {\n" +
        "                if (line > 0)\n" +
        "                {\n" +
        "                    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(pos, 1.0f);\n" +
        "                    _alpha = float(line) / 255.0f;\n" +
        "                }\n" +
        "                else\n" +
        "                {\n" +
        "                    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0f);\n" +
        "                    _alpha = abs(player_y - obj_y) >= 3.0f ? 0.25f : 1.0f;\n" +
        "                }\n" +
        "            }"
        );

    var pixel_shader = make_shader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"#version 300 es\n" +
        "\n" +
        "precision highp float;\n            " +
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n" +
        "            in float _alpha;\n" +
        "            uniform vec3 color;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "            void main()\n" +
        "            {\n" +
        "                FragColor = vec4(color, _alpha);\n" +
        "            }"




        );

    gl.attachShader(gfx.shader, vtx_shader);
    gl.attachShader(gfx.shader, pixel_shader);
    gl.linkProgram(gfx.shader);
    if ( !gl.getProgramParameter( gfx.shader, gl.LINK_STATUS) ) {
        var info = gl.getProgramInfoLog(gfx.shader);
        alert('Could not compile WebGL program. \n\n' + info);
    }
    var vertices = [
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 0.0,

        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,

        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,

        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,

        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,

        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0
];
    gfx.vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gfx.vbo = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindVertexArray(gfx.vao);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gfx.vbo);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0,3,gl.FLOAT, false,5*4,0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(1,2,gl.FLOAT, false,5*4,3*4);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);

    gfx.line_vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gfx.line_vbo = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindVertexArray(gfx.line_vao);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gfx.line_vbo);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0,3,gl.FLOAT, false,3*4,0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    resize_gfx(gfx, width, height);

    return gfx;



}

function make_shader(type, shader) {
  var handle = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(handle, shader);
  gl.compileShader(handle);

  var success = gl.getShaderParameter(handle, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (!success) {
    var info = gl.getShaderInfoLog(handle);

    alert(info);
  }


  return handle;
}

function resize_gfx(state,width,height) {
    gl.viewport(0,0,width,height);
    state.width = width;
    state.height = height;
}

function GraphicState() {

    var ctx;
    var window;

    var shader;
    var vao;
    var vbo;
    var line_vao;
    var line_vbo;

    var width;
    var height;

}

/*function draw_text(x, y, z , scale, txt, r, g, b, a, view, proj) {
    var text = glt.createText();
    glt.setText(text, txt);
    glt.beginDraw();
    glt.color(r/255.0,g/255.0,b/255.0,a/255.0);
    glt.drawText3D(text, x, y, z, scale, view, proj);
    glt.endDraw();
    glt.deleteText(text);


}*/

function draw_line (x, y, z, to_x, to_y, to_z, r, g, b, a) {
    var vertices = [
        x,y,z,
        to_x,to_y,to_z
    ];

    gl.useProgram(gfx.shader);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "line"), a);
    gl.uniform3f(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader,"color"),r/255.0,g/255.0,b/255.0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,gfx.line_vbo);
    gl.bindVertexArray(gfx.line_vao);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 2);




}

function get_forward_vec(pitch, yaw, pos) {
    var elevation = glm.radians(-pitch);
    var heading = glm.radians(yaw);
    var forward_vec = glm.vec3(Math.cos(elevation) * Math.sin(heading), Math.sin(elevation), Math.cos(elevation) * Math.cos(heading));
    return forward_vec;
}

function render() {
    var projection = glm.perspective(glm.radians(75.0), gfx.width / gfx.height, 0.1, 2000.0);
    projection = glm.scale(projection, glm.vec3(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
    var player_y = 0.0;
    var player_forward_vec;


    //TODO get Player
    player_y = 0;
    var pitch = 0;
    var yaw = 0;
    var cam_at = glm.vec3(0, 0 + 1.5, 0);
    player_forward_vec = get_forward_vec(pitch, yaw, cam_at);
   //var cam_look = glm.vec3(11, 11 + 1.5, 11) + get_forward_vec(pitch, yaw, cam_at);
    var sumx = cam_at.x + player_forward_vec.x;
    var sumy = cam_at.y + player_forward_vec.y;
    var sumz = cam_at.z + player_forward_vec.z;
    var cam_look = glm.vec3(sumx,sumy,sumz);

    var ls = glm.vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    var view = glm.lookAt(cam_at, cam_look, ls);




    gl.useProgram(gfx.shader);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "player_y"), player_y);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "projection"),  false,projection.array);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "view"),  false, view.array);

    var at = glm.vec3(3, 2, 1);
    var look = at + (get_forward_vec(0, 0, at) * 50.0);
    look.y += 1.5;
    draw_line(at.x, at.y, at.z, look.x, look.y, look.z, 0, 255, 0, 255);

}

function get_alpha_for_y (y1,y2) {
    return Math.abs(y1 - y2) >= 3.0 ? 63 : 255;
}

start();
```

```html
<canvas id="glcanvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glm-js@0.0.6-c/build/glm-js.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is this line

```
var look = at + (get_forward_vec(0, 0, at) * 50.0);
```

JavaScript doesn't support operator overloading. glm-js says to do it like this

```
var look = at['+'](get_forward_vec(0, 0, at)['*='](50.0));
```

honestly glm-js looks pretty horrible for JavaScript and especially for perf.

A second issue is you didn't look up your attribute locations nor did you assign any so if it runs it was just lucky that pos came out to location 0 and color to location 1

Also [multiline template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are your friend

Also Also, when asking a debugging question you're required to make your code **minimal**. There are 20-30 lines of commented out code irrelevant to your question

Also, Also, Also, It's more common to make 2 shaders than to have 1 shader that has a conditional

```js
var gl; // 
var canvas;
var gfx;
function start() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
  gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');


    gfx = make_gfx();



      gl.clearColor(0.9,0.9,0.8,1);
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


     render();
    draw_line(10,10,10,100,100,100,0,0,255);
}


function make_gfx() {
    var gfx = new GraphicState();
        gfx.ctx = gl;
        gfx.window = canvas;
        gfx.shader = gl.createProgram();

    var vtx_shader = make_shader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, `#version 300 es
        layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
        layout (location = 1) in vec2 tex_coord;
        
        out float _alpha;

        uniform mat4 model;
        uniform mat4 view;
        uniform mat4 projection;
        uniform int line;
        uniform float player_y;
        uniform float obj_y;

        void main()
        {
            if (line > 0)
            {
                gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(pos, 1.0f);
                _alpha = float(line) / 255.0f;
            }
            else
            {
                gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0f);
                _alpha = abs(player_y - obj_y) >= 3.0f ? 0.25f : 1.0f;
            }
        }
        `);

    var pixel_shader = make_shader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER,`#version 300 es
        
        precision highp float;
        out vec4 FragColor;
        in float _alpha;
        uniform vec3 color;

        void main()
        {
            FragColor = vec4(color, _alpha);
        }

        `);
    gl.attachShader(gfx.shader, vtx_shader);
    gl.attachShader(gfx.shader, pixel_shader);
    gl.linkProgram(gfx.shader);
    if ( !gl.getProgramParameter( gfx.shader, gl.LINK_STATUS) ) {
        var info = gl.getProgramInfoLog(gfx.shader);
        alert('Could not compile WebGL program. \n\n' + info);
    }
    var vertices = [
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 0.0,

        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,

        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,

        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,

        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,

        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0
];
    gfx.vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gfx.vbo = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindVertexArray(gfx.vao);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gfx.vbo);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0,3,gl.FLOAT, false,5*4,0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(1,2,gl.FLOAT, false,5*4,3*4);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);

    gfx.line_vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gfx.line_vbo = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindVertexArray(gfx.line_vao);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gfx.line_vbo);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0,3,gl.FLOAT, false,3*4,0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    resize_gfx(gfx, width, height);

    return gfx;



}

function make_shader(type, shader) {
  var handle = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(handle, shader);
  gl.compileShader(handle);

  var success = gl.getShaderParameter(handle, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (!success) {
    var info = gl.getShaderInfoLog(handle);

    alert(info);
  }


  return handle;
}

function resize_gfx(state,width,height) {
    gl.viewport(0,0,width,height);
    state.width = width;
    state.height = height;
}

function GraphicState() {

    var ctx;
    var window;

    var shader;
    var vao;
    var vbo;
    var line_vao;
    var line_vbo;

    var width;
    var height;

}

function draw_line (x, y, z, to_x, to_y, to_z, r, g, b, a) {
    var vertices = [
        x,y,z,
        to_x,to_y,to_z
    ];

    gl.useProgram(gfx.shader);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "line"), a);
    gl.uniform3f(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader,"color"),r/255.0,g/255.0,b/255.0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,gfx.line_vbo);
    gl.bindVertexArray(gfx.line_vao);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 2);




}

function get_forward_vec(pitch, yaw, pos) {
    var elevation = glm.radians(-pitch);
    var heading = glm.radians(yaw);
    var forward_vec = glm.vec3(Math.cos(elevation) * Math.sin(heading), Math.sin(elevation), Math.cos(elevation) * Math.cos(heading));
    return forward_vec;
}

function render() {
    var projection = glm.perspective(glm.radians(75.0), gfx.width / gfx.height, 0.1, 2000.0);
    projection = glm.scale(projection, glm.vec3(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
    var player_y = 0.0;
    var player_forward_vec;


    //TODO get Player
    player_y = 0;
    var pitch = 0;
    var yaw = 0;
    var cam_at = glm.vec3(0, 0 + 1.5, 0);
    player_forward_vec = get_forward_vec(pitch, yaw, cam_at);
   //var cam_look = glm.vec3(11, 11 + 1.5, 11) + get_forward_vec(pitch, yaw, cam_at);
    var sumx = cam_at.x + player_forward_vec.x;
    var sumy = cam_at.y + player_forward_vec.y;
    var sumz = cam_at.z + player_forward_vec.z;
    var cam_look = glm.vec3(sumx,sumy,sumz);

    var ls = glm.vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    var view = glm.lookAt(cam_at, cam_look, ls);




    gl.useProgram(gfx.shader);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "player_y"), player_y);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "projection"),  false,projection.array);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(gfx.shader, "view"),  false, view.array);

    var at = glm.vec3(3, 2, 1);
    var look = at['+'](get_forward_vec(0, 0, at)['*='](50.0));
    look.y += 1.5;
    draw_line(at.x, at.y, at.z, look.x, look.y, look.z, 0, 255, 0, 255);

}

function get_alpha_for_y (y1,y2) {
    return Math.abs(y1 - y2) >= 3.0 ? 63 : 255;
}

start();
```

```html
<canvas id="glcanvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glm-js@0.0.6-c/build/glm-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you recommend me something to replace glm?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation. Some people use [gl-matrix](http://glmatrix.net/) but i'm not personally a fan.